# Why does spectrogram's result matrix not have the length of the chosen window?

Tags: matlab

I am learning about audio processing techniques and have been using a spectrogram to do analysis. Now, I would have thought that the result of the spectrogram would be an M x N matrix, where M would be the window length, and N the number of windows. However the spectrogram function returns a matrix of a different length than I would expect:

```
data = [...]; % the data, a 1 x 9171 array

wdw = 160; %  window size

overlap = 80; % window overlap

numWindows = floor(length(data)/(wdw - overlap)) - 1; % returns 113 as expected

nfft = 256; % fft size

Fs = 16000; % sample freq

s = spectrogram(data,hamming(wdw),overlap,nfft,Fs);
```

s returns as a 129 x 113 matrix, whereas I would expect a 160 x 113 matrix. Does anyone know why the function truncates the length of each window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `S` returns what you think it returns. From the documentation:

> Each column of S contains an estimate of the short-term, time-localized
>       frequency content of the signal X.  Time increases across the columns
>       of S, from left to right.  Frequency increases down the rows, starting
>       at 0.  If X is a length NX complex signal, S is a complex matrix with
>       NFFT rows and k = fix((NX-NOVERLAP)/(length(WINDOW)-NOVERLAP)) columns.
>       **For real X, S has (NFFT/2+1) rows if NFFT is even**, and (NFFT+1)/2 rows
>       if NFFT is odd.

129 is 256/2+1, which is what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Why were you expecting 160 anyway? 160 is just the size of your window. Because of this size and the overlap, you get a number of "windowings" equal to 113. For each such "windowing" you get its frequency content, expressed in a "frequency resolution" of 256 points.

It's been a while since I've dealt with spectra, but, the "divide by two" business presumably has to do with the fourier spectrum symmetry around the 0-axis

Comment: I was thinking that it would be performing `fft(windowArray)` on each window, and I know `fft(X)` returns an array with the same size as `X`, though as you pointed out its doing `fft(X,n)`. I am familiar with the halving of the spectrum in finding the single sided spectrum of the signal.